# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: oracle, line, ora-06550

When call a parameter show this error what is the issue I don't understand. I am new user :-(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cust_order_sample
( 
order_po_num IN Number,
sale_order_num OUT Number
)
As
BEGIN
select CONTROLLING_MANAGER INTO sale_order_num from FND_CONC_REQ_SUMMARY_V  WHERE ARGUMENT_TEXT=order_po_num;
END 
cust_order_sample;
```

And when I run this procedure:

```
execute cust_order_sample(28685);
```

I get this error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUST_ORDER_SAMPLE'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: You have an out parameter.  Where do you expect the results to go?

Comment: yes i want to do

Comment: To elaborate on OldProgrammer's comment: you may create a bind variable, for example `x`, with a command like `variable x number`. You can assign a value to it and print the value, with the two commands `exec :x := 10` and `print x`. The last command will print the value 10. Then you can call your procedure like so: `exec cust_order_sample(28685, :x)` - that will place the value from your view (or whatever that is) into the variable `x`. Now you can use that value wherever you need it, in your PL/SQL code or a parameterized query, etc. Your call to the procedure is missing the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a bind variable to store the OUT parameter value.  In SQLPLUS, this will work:

```
var nvar number;
execute cust_order_sample(111, :nvar);
print nvar;
```

Comment: Also, you can do that with simple script: declare v_out number; begin cust_order_sample(111, v_out); end;

Comment: Then you have to use dbms_output to see the results.